# Get number of # characters at the beginning of text with regex

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to find out that this string:

```
#### This is just a string
```

has 4 `#` characters at the beginning, with `regex` in PHP? Basically returning the amount of those characters. I am looking for a one line solution

It must only find those characters at the beginning of the string

Comment: You could do `preg_replace` and `strlen`, is that a one liner? https://eval.in/836976

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Use `if (preg_match("/^#+/", "#### This is just a string", $matches))` then check length of match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`\G` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) which matches at start of string or where previous match ended.

```
echo preg_match_all('/\G#/', $str);
```

> 4

[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/836978)

Comment: Variant: `echo preg_match_all('/#/A', $str);`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Good input! Didn't know this flag yet. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

A combination of `strlen` and `ltrim` calls can do the trick pretty nicely:

```
$numHashes = strlen($str) - strlen(ltrim($str, '#'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not Regex, but you can use the built in fucntion to count the substring (#) in the main string:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

```
$text = 'This is a test';
echo substr_count($text, 'is'); // 2
```

See more examples at php.net

Good luck

David